# Problems when writing to a .txt file on Windows 10

Tags: java, text-files, windows-10, fileoutputstream, bufferedwriter

I have created a program which generates primes (use the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm) and give the user an opportunity to choose where the results are outpuuted too; the console, a text file, or both.

When writing to the text file though, I am having some problems. on `Mac OS X`, it works fine, although on `Windows 10` I have trouble when writing more than a few hundred numbers to the file. The program I open the results in is notepad, so I'm thinking, is this a notepad issue? I have provided the code used to write to the text file and an example of what is shown in the text file when I try to write all of the primes below `25000` to it.

My code:

```
private static void outputPrimesToFile(boolean [] primeNumbers, int maxPrime) {
    try{
        String fileName = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Primes below " + maxPrime + ".txt";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if(file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        System.out.println("\nCreating file...");
        file.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("Writing results to file...");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        String encoding = System.getProperty("file.encoding");
        try (Writer bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, encoding))) {
            for (int i = 2; i < primeNumbers.length; i++) {
                if(primeNumbers[i]) {
                    bw.append(i + " ");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Success. Exiting...");
    }catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

What is shown in the text file on Windows 10:

[image]

- I have also tried using the following:

> try (Writer bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8"))

Although I still get the same result in the text file.

> **Update:**
>
> I have tried opening the file on Windows 10 in Microsoft Word with the default encoding, and it works fine, displaying the numbers as it should, which bring me back to the question, is the an issue with the program Notepad on Windows 10?

Comment: Seems like a bug with Notepad http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx. Just use a real editor ! **Edit :** this post seems old, but maybe it has not changed since then. After all, Notepad is really a poor edito and no one expects it to be frequently updated because no one uses it

Comment: You don't seem to be closing or flushing buffer

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you, I had forgotten that, although that has not made any difference to the output to the file, I do believe it is a Notepad issue upon further research as [@Dici](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32089467/problems-when-writing-to-a-txt-file-on-windows-10?noredirect=1#comment52074322_32089467) said!

Comment: drop notepad, it's bs. Use sublime or notepad++

Comment: @Dici I understand what you're saying, I never normally use Notepad, it's just that Notepad is the default program for opening .txt files in Windows, so I've now changed that!

Comment: @MadProgrammer No, he **is** closing the writer, since he is using it within a `try-catch`. This is the recommended way to do it ! `try-catch` exists for that : closing the resources whatever happens

Comment: @dic Plain old try-catch does not close the rescourses, you're thinking of try-with-rescourses which is different. This is why you typically see the finally block used to close the resources in pre-Java 7 code

Comment: That's the case here, that's what I meant. You're right to fix my explanation. His code is fine however